# Understanding html/body height property and sticky footer (not fixed)

Tags: html, css

I've been consulting a lot of threads regarding sticky footers (footer sticking to the bottom of the page even if there is few content) and as much as theses workarounds can do the trick, I find them kind of messy and don't understand why simpler things don't work.

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
html {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px); //container's height - (header height + footer height)
}

header, footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

The problem I have with this code is that the body won't respect the `height: 100%` property and will just wrap around the body content instead of expanding to 100% of its container which is `html`.
The html tag is working properly, its minimum height is the viewport and will expand with `height: auto;` if the content is larger than the viewport.

Why won't the body expand to 100% of the html's height ?
I've tried my code and it works perfectly if I set html's height to a pixel value, the body will expand to 100% of html. But it won't expand if html's height is auto.

I can't neither set html's height to 100% (even tho then the body will expand to fill the html tag) because when content goes bellow 100% of the viewport, the html won't expand to contain the content, it will just overflow.

Is there something I'm missing ? How can I make this work ?

**edit :**
Thanks for all the insightful answers and comments !
Here is the best way to do this I could come up with :

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px); //container's height - (header height + footer height)
}

header, footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Doing so will make the `main` content to expand if the content is longer than the viewport, or stay at the bottom of the page if the content is shorter than the viewport.
Since my header and footer have relative positioning I subtract their height to the `main` minimum height so the footer always fit in the viewport when there is few content, while not triggering the scrollbar to show up.

The only downside to this method is that `main` will overflow from the `body` and `html` element (since their `height: 100%` is the viewport's height but it doesn't affect the way the page will render, and seems to be working.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the `html` element doesn't have an explicit height, so the `height: 100%;` rule on `body` doesn't have a value to use as reference. I can't really explain the theory behind why this happens though, but you can [have a look here](http://codepen.io/ZaLiTHkA/pen/oBqPeP) to see it in action.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. But I can neither find an explanation nor a work-around with this. Myabe dynamically adjust html's height with JQuery ? I have no idea.

Comment: I would advise against using jQuery for that; it's unnecessary overhead that will cause you headaches down the road. CSS is more than capable of handling this for you. Also keep in mind that the markup structure makes a huge difference to these sort of points, so er-han's answer here should be of particular interest to you.

Comment: I agree, Jquery came to my mind out of despair, but I think I may have found my path into this and will try a couple things.

Comment: Your code is fine, and works in Edge/Firefox/Chrome, except IE. `calc` is not properly supported in IE 11, and you can see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc that most known issues are bout IE 11. BTW, you need to set height: 100% for html, and no need for min-height.

Comment: I am glad you have found the solution. But i wonder if your code's last edition works in IE too, I mean the calc() function

Comment: I haven't tested on IE myself, but most support tables indicate that it should be ok for IE 11+. This method may not fit for someone needing compatibility with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code works perfectly on my local. But, i know this is a general issue with most versions of browsers that `html` and `body` height may not behave correctly. They sometimes behave differently than espected with your approach.

You can try my approach, which i use for years and am satisfied with the result. I don't try to force `html` and `body` heights.

HTML structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header></header>
            <main></main>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the style is:

```
<style>
header, footer {
    height: 50px;
}

#page {
    min-height:100%;
}

main {
    padding-bottom:50px;/* This is related to the footer's height */
}

footer {
    margin-top: -50px;/* This is related to the footer's height */
}
</style>
```

If you want the footer **always** stay on the bottom, even if the page content is higher than the viewport, just replace `#page`'s `min-height` attribute with `height` like this:

```
#page {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: This is a work-around that would indeed be working, and will be my back-up solution. However I'm a bit stubborn and not quite ready to give up on this html height matter haha. I just need to understand why it won't work. Thanks !

Comment: @eloism that's the spirit! lol, please let me notify or post it as an answer here if you figure it out. I wonder it too

Comment: Indeed after a few tests I think I may have found the simplest way to do this,  I've edited my post. Also checks out GCyrillus's post which does a similar thing but make the scrollbars appear around `main` instead of the `body`. It can be interesting for some websites (like mine). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider `flex` ? It does require very litlle CSS

example header & footer fixed:

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;/* % needs a value from parent to be calculated, except for html wich takes window for reference. If you skip html, then body's height is 100% of null .... */
  margin:0;
}

/* layout */
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }

main {
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
  
  /* see me */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
  }
```

```html
    <header>Any<br/> height </header>
    <main> whatever, <br/>i'll be showing a scrollbr instead pushing against footer.</main>
    <footer> any height</footer>
```

footer fixed :

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;/* % needs a value from parent to be calculated, except for html wich takes window for reference. If you skip html, then body's height is 100% of null .... */
  margin:0;
}

/* layout */
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }

section {
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
  
  /* see me */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <header>header</header>
    <main>and the rest </main>
  </section>
    <footer> any height footer remaining at window bottom</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is an interesting work-around. The only flaw of this method is that both the header and footer end up being fixed when scrolling up or down : /

Comment: @eloism if put header and main together , then , only the footer remains visible. *added a snippet to show how easy this technics is*

Answer (score 0):

Replace Main with Section and it should give the output as you requested.

**DOM**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header>asdf</header>
    <section>asdf</section>
    <footer>asdf</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

section{
  height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px);
}

header, footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it gives me the same result as with `main` : the body doesn't expand to html's height and just wrapped around `section`

Comment: I just added the output. Is this what you need to accomplish? If yes, the code above should be working for you as well.

Comment: This is indeed what I'm trying to do ! However the `html height: auto` seems to be blocking the body from expanding in my case. I will try different things out and see how it works before updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stackoverflow</title>
        <style>
            header {
                position: absolute; 
                right:0; 
                left:0; 
                top: 0; 
                background: yellow; 
                height: 50px;
            }
            main {    
                position: relative;
                min-width: 100%;
                margin-top: 50px;
                height: 100vh;
                background: green;}
            footer {
                position: fixed; 
                right:0; left:0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                background: blue; 
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <main></main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```